# Why does storing attribute in xsl:variable result in error XTDE0420?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This XSLT constructs an attribute and stores the result in a variable. Then the variable is copied as the only child of element `<test>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">    

  <xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:variable name="some-attribute">
      <xsl:attribute name="test">value</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:variable>
    <test>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$some-attribute" />
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although this seems to simply insert an attribute as the child of an element, the result is to throw an error: `XTDE0420: Cannot create an attribute node whose parent is a document node`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key information is explained in [section 9.3 of the XSLT 2.0 spec, "Values of Variables and Parameters"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variable-values):

> If a variable-binding element has no select attribute and has
>   non-empty content (that is, the variable-binding element has one or
>   more child nodes), and has no as attribute, then the content of the
>   variable-binding element specifies the supplied value. **The content of
>   the variable-binding element is a sequence constructor; *a new document
>   is constructed with a document node* having as its children the
>   sequence of nodes that results from evaluating the sequence
>   constructor** and then applying the rules given in 5.7.1 Constructing
>   Complex Content. The value of the variable is then a singleton
>   sequence containing this document node. For further information, see
>   9.4 Creating implicit document nodes.

Essentially, the value of a variable without a `select` attribute and without an `as` attribute is a document node.

It's not possible to modify the variable in the example to use `select`, but it can be changed to use `as`:

```
<xsl:variable name="some-attribute" as="item()*">
  <xsl:attribute name="test">value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:variable>
```